# How to store the array of string in shared preferences?

Tags: android

How to store the array of String in SharedPreferences? And please give me an example code for storing array few names and retrieve it in another activity. Thanks in advance

Comment: post the code what you have tried

Comment: I do not have any idea of it please give your answers

Comment: @SimonChius: FYI: If you don't post the codes you have tried, you'll get a lot of negative votes. I personally don't downvote on newcomers as I know you guys are not yet familiar with SO posting rules and guidelines.

Comment: well I guess that each newcomer should read the rules @ChuongPham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        private Button button;
        private SharedPreferences preferences;
        private String[] name = {"aa", "bb", "cc"};
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            preferences=getSharedPreferences("testarray", MODE_PRIVATE);
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("str"+i, name[i]);
                editor.commit();
            }
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Secondact.class));               
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

second activity

```
public class Secondact extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button button;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        preferences = getSharedPreferences("testarray", MODE_PRIVATE);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                {
                    Log.d("aa", preferences.getString("str"+i, " "));
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

using set of strings

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button button;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private String[] name = {"aa", "bb", "cc"};
    Set<String> values = new HashSet<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        preferences=getSharedPreferences("testarray", MODE_PRIVATE);
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            values.add(name[i]);
        }

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
                {

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
                    editor.putStringSet("str", values);
                    editor.commit();
                }
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Secondact.class));               
            }
        });
    }

}


public class Secondact extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button button;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        preferences = getSharedPreferences("testarray", MODE_PRIVATE);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Set<String> values = preferences.getStringSet("str", null);

                String[] name = values.toArray(new String[values.size()]);
                for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
                    Log.d("aa", name[i]);
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use string set. but it requires a min API level of 11.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try and help you

First of all set up these class variables in the Activities you want to use SharedPreferences

```
public static String MY_PREFS = "MY_PREFS";
private SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences;
int prefMode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
```

Then to store the string values like this

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("key1", "value1");
editor.putString("key2", "value2");
editor.putString("key3", "value3");

editor.commit(); // to persist the values between activities
```

and the finally to access the sharedPreferences in another activity use this

```
mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, prefMode);
String string1 = mySharedPreferences.getString("key1", null);
String string2 = mySharedPreferences.getString("key2", null);
```

hope this helps you a lil bit.

Comment: sorry dude. i asked for array of string

Comment: sorry i've never used arrays before in sharedPreferences i think you should check out the other answer

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not supported. However you can store a Set.

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = parent.getContext().getSharedPreferences(
            "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> values = new HashSet<String>();
    values.add("value 1");
    values.add("value 2");
    prefs.edit().putStringSet("myKey", values).commit();
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to retrieve

Comment: Set<String> values = prefs.getStringSet("myKey");

Comment: The method getStringSet(String, Set<String>) in the type SharedPreferences is not applicable for the arguments (String)   when i use this code to retrive data

Comment: getStringSet(String) only has the key to retrieve the set. The setStringSet has the set as parameter to set the new values. getStringSet(String, Set<String>) doesn't make sense. What should it do?